# Control two websites from a Administrator

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have two websites in my local development server, 'sample' and 'example', And I have a common administrator('cms/admin') for both.
Both sites functionality will be the same, But CSS, DB and Menu layouts only different. So I have created a Backend to manage those things.And the front End will be developed based on Dynamic CSS, Menu and DB,
              If I am going to run the 'sample', I will get the directory name, based on that fetch all CSS,DB and Menu template values from Admin DB and using that will showed the sites, This is concept.

### Directory Structure

cms

- whole Project(Developed by CAKEPHP)

sample

- .htaccess

example

- .htaccess

As of Now, I have created Administrator.
When I am going to run a 'sample', It will goes to sample directory, there is .htaccess, that .htaccess will redirect to main cms directory, which have all functionalities.
So the URL remaining('sample') the same, But the functionality will from the main Directory (cms).
So please advice me how to do that? Is this possible or Is there anyother way to implement this concept. The whole project will be developed by CakePHP only.'

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change conception of application:

- Seems it should be one cakephp application,
- Application should  use [cakephp themes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html) in `beforeFilter` of `AppController.php` you should check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and use one or another theme
- in AppModel you can use right database config.
- for admin panel ( cms) seems you should use admin routing [check it here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

Comment: Yes you are right, I have created admin using that routing method, But My problem is in, When am going to run a 'sample' project, that will search for that directory, But actual related functionalities are in 'cms' only.Because they were two different sites, the url should be different one, In that situation How can I implement this?

Comment: not sure, that I understand you, but I think application should be placed in one folder. it's just one application. You will define several virtual hosts or one with alices and same DocumentRoot. and after that recognize by HTTP_HOST which site exactly requested now

Comment: maybe you can provide some more code, so, we can provide more concrete answers